# Is there any asynchronous operation in Javascript BESIDES hhtp request /timeSetout & setInterval?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

I searched a lot and just wanted to double check: the only asynchronous operations in javascript are the timesetOut and setinterval method as well as http requests?!
Is there any way to make a 'regular' (not a timesetOut/setinterval) callback behave blocking/asynchronous?
Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript (the language) doesn't actually provide any way to defer execution of a function. `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are browser/DOM APIs. The environment you are running your code in might or might not provide such functionality.

Comment: ^ I guess that's not quite correct. Promises are guaranteed to not be process before the next tick of the event loop.

Comment: Okay I see, I always read callbacks when it comes to async operations, but then based on what you say no callbacks work asynchronous (unless some enviroment would provide that)?! Also, I guess promises work that way not because of 'themselves' but they are probably 'implemented' by all browsers like timesetOut is implemented by certain browsers?!

Comment: *"I guess promises work that way not because of 'themselves' [...]"* Well, the spec dictates that they have to behave like this. The spec also defines event queues and stuff. It just doesn't specify a user land API to add something to that queue. While callbacks are necessary for async, they are not async themselves. Simple example: `[1,2,3].map( x => x+1)`.

Comment: " While callbacks are necessary for async, they are not async themselves" so if something is async - which is only http requests (the libraries making http requests) / setTimeout and setInterval - THEY require a callback to work as intended which is async. However, if I dont use that, any callback I pass into a regular function will become blocking since callbacks are not async themselves. Correct?! :)

Comment: @javascripting There's nothing "blocking" about a callback. What matters is when the callback will be called.

Comment: if callbacks in general are not asynchronous, unless you pass your callback either to a setTimeout or a setInterval - it will be blocking because in any other case it would get added on top of the outer function in the callstack, thus executed right away and while this happens other code execution would be blocked. If thats not the case, callbacks would be asynchronous. So what do you mean by 'when will the callback be called' - in all cases except for settimeout/setinterval?!